# Apache log : 'myipha.php not found or unable to stat' and others

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I recently get in my apache error.log a long set of :

```
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:22.005214 2016] [:error] [pid 15759] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myiphb.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:27.164111 2016] [:error] [pid 15644] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myiphb.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:32.314190 2016] [:error] [pid 15757] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myiphd.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:37.462354 2016] [:error] [pid 15514] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myiphd.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:42.559487 2016] [:error] [pid 15760] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myiphb.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:42.606343 2016] [:error] [pid 15760] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myiphd.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:42.653108 2016] [:error] [pid 15760] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myipha.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Jun 30 13:03:42.699306 2016] [:error] [pid 15760] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] script '/var/www/html/myiphc.php' not found or unable to stat
```

The PID belongs to apache. I couldn't find much on the internet about it.

Anyone knows what it is ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the results of that error is either the script doesn't exist. Or the permissions settings for that script are invalid. Double check that it's where it's being looked for and that apache has proper permissions to the file.

Comment: But what is calling this ?

Comment: A backdoor attack bot. Use this to prevent future problems: https://github.com/acosonic/fail2ban_custom_rules (they are Wordpress crawlers that try to infect your system)